# Regex: Select a particular tag from a text and replace with another tag

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, regex, tags

I have a lot of html files, and I must doing a search and replace with regex. So, I must select a particular tag `<span class="text_obisnuit">text<\p>` and replace it with another tag.

For example:

`<p><span class="text_obisnuit">My text here.</span></p>`

should become:

`<p class="text_obisnuit">My text here.</p>`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I didn't try. I am a web designer, not a programmer... :( Sorry

Comment: A regular expression doesn't have anything to do with programming. Using search and replace in a GUI application isn't hard. Something like regex101.com should allow you to get an idea and easily try some stuff. The closing p tag in your initial statement is malformed as the slash is the wrong way around.

Comment: must be something like this `(?s).*<p><span class="text_obisnuit">(?s)(.*)</span></p>` REPLACE BY: \1<p>\3<p>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `<p\K><span([^>]*?class="text_obisnuit"[^>]*>.*?)</span>(?=</p)`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<p                          # literally
\K                          # forget all we have seen until this position
><span                      # literally
(                           # start group 1
  [^>]*?                    # 0 or more any character that is not >, not greedy
  class="text_obisnuit"     # literally
  [^>]*                     # 0 or more any character that is not >
  >                         # literally
  .*?                       # 0 or more any character, not greedy
)                           # end group 1
</span>                     # literally
(?=</p)                     # positive lookahead, make sure we have </p> after
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          # content of group 1, the class and the text
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: Toto, must be that particular tag, not all tags that contains <span>  :)

Comment: @JustMe: see my edit.

Comment: :) Toto saying, only this tag  `<span class="text_obisnuit">`  and not other tags like `<span class="my_text">`  Your regex will match all those `<span class>`. I need only the tag with clas named: `"text_obisnuit"`

Answer (score 0):

FIND = `(?s)<p><span (.*?class="text_obisnuit".*?)>(.*?)</span></p>`

REPLACE = `<p $1>$2</p>`

MODE = regular expression

SOURCE: https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/18719/regex-replace-tag-with-another-tag-from-text/5